# spring integration error handling on message chain

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

I am trying to achieve error handling for spring integration flow in which I am consuming message from kafka, transforming message into object and processing it after.

I am consuming message from kafka topic and first thing I want to do transform that json message to object for which I am using int:json-to-object-transformer/ which can throw JsonProcessingException, I am simply using

```
<int:chain input-channel="kafkaInputChannel" output-channel="kafkaOutputChannel">
        <int:json-to-object-transformer object-mapper="customObjectMapper" type="com.test.spring.int.User"/>
</int:chain>
```

How can I handle that exception with above code, I don't see int:request-handler-advice-chain available inside chain above and also I want to stop processing that message after receiving JsonProcessingException as it will throw null pointers for the flow after transforming that message, could you please tell how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `error-channel` to the upstream Kafka channel adapter and consume `ErrorMessage`s from that channel. The payload is a `MessagingException` with `cause` and `failedMessage` properties.